# REGEX to Include File with no Extensions and All Extensions Except Certain Ones (PNG or JPG)

Tags: python, regex, file-type

I am trying to come up with a `regex` to only filterout one or more certain type (extension) of files while scanning a root folder using `os.walk`. My Folder structure (to be searched) looks like this. Note the files with no extension.

```
Directory: D:\Projects\5 Codes Cleaned\2012

SG
|---SG.zip
|---SOIL-Average.jpg
|---SWAT-Average.jpg
|---Test
1500_LT_Capped_2012
1500_LT_Capped_2012
1500_LT_Capped_2012
1500_LT_Capped_2012
1500_LT_Capped_2012
1500_LT_Capped_2012
1500_LT_Capped_2012
1500_LT_Capped_2012
PRESSURE-Average.png
SGAS-Average.png
SOIL-Average.png
SWAT-Average.png
```

or in list format:

```
[u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -P',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -P.npy',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -Sg',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -Sg.npy',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -So',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -So.npy',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -Sw',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\1500_LT_Capped_2012 -Sw.npy',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\PRESSURE-Average.png',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\SGAS-Average.png',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\SOIL-Average.png',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\SWAT-Average.png',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\SG\\SG.zip',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\SG\\SOIL-Average.jpg',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\SG\\SWAT-Average.jpg',
 u'D:\\Projects\\5 Codes Cleaned\\2012\\SG\\Test']
```

I looked up some of the threads going on here to get some ideas but I am wondering if there is any easier way to do it. So far I've tried below patterns to filter out `os.walk` 
results:

```
regex = "^.*(?<!\.png)(?<!\.npy)$"    
# The only working one but tends to get messy 
# as more file types are to be excluded!
```

&

```
regex = "^(.+?)(?:\.(?:png|jpg))*$"   
# Does not filter out jpg or png...list all files
```

&

```
regex = '^.*\.(?!jpg$|png$)[^.]+$'    
# Filters out png & jpg but Does not include No-Extensions !
```

&

```
regex = '^.*\.*(?!.jpg$|.png$)'     
# Does not filter out png & jpg file
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just use `os.path.splitext` and a list comprehension?

```
disallowed_types = ['png', 'jpg']

allowed = [x for x in allfiles if os.path.splitext(x)[1] not in disallowed_types]
```

but if you must use regex, this appears to work, but inverted:

```
regex = '[^.]*?\.+(jpg$|png$)'
```

so then if it matches this, it's a jpg or png and should not be included, else it's safe and can be included in the list.

Comment: That's a great way for this specific task. However, I am trying to write a general purpose pattern filtering for os.walk to be used everywhere in my various codes. So, I am leaning toward regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
>>> extensions = "png jpg npy".split()
>>> regex = "^.*%s$"
>>> regex%"".join("(?<!\.%s)"%i for i in extensions)
'^.*(?<!\\.png)(?<!\\.jpg)(?<!\\.npy)$'
```

And then:

```
all = [...]
# If you want to get all files with extension `'jpg', 'png', '...'`:

[i for i in [compiled.match(x) for x in a] if not i]

# Will get you all files with no extension, with .png or with .jpg

# If you want all OTHER files (like .zip):

[i for i in [compiled.match(x) for x in a] if i]
```